# How to combine rows of 2 tables having some columns same and some different

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, join, union-all

I have two tables for user posts, one for text post and one for multimedia post, the structure of both tables is as follows.

table **text_post**

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
| postid | post_content | post_user | post_type | post_visibility | post_date |
+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

table **multimedia_post**

```
+-------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+
|post_id|post_content|post_url|post_user|post_type|post_visibility|post_date|
+-------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

in text_post `post_content` is text data that posted by user and in multimedia_post `post_content` is caption text that is associated with multimedia file, so basically `post_content` is text matter. all columns are common, only the post_url is different in multimedia_post, I want to combine result of these two table as follows

```
+-------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+
|post_id|post_content|post_url|post_user|post_type|post_visibility|post_date|
+-------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+
|  1    |  some text | null   | 1       | <type>  | <visibility>  | <date>  |
+-------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+
|  1    | img_caption| <url>  | 1       | <type>  | <visibility>  | <date>  |
+-------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+
..and so on
```

here 1st row returned is from `text_post` so `post_url` is set to null because only `multimedia_post` has that column...and second row is from `multimedia_post` as there is url of the post...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UNION ALL` from two `SELECT`s that return columns that "line up", like this:

```
SELECT
    postid as post_id
,   post_content
,   null as post_url
,   post_user
... -- the rest of text_post columns included in the select
FROM text_post
UNION ALL
SELECT
    post_id
,   img_caption as post_content
,   post_url
,   post_user
... -- the rest of multimedia_post columns included in the select
FROM multimedia_post
```

Note how `null as post_url` is selected from `text_post`: this is necessary in order to line up the columns of the two select statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION

```
SELECT 
  postid, post_content, NULL, post_user, post_type, post_visibility, post_date 
FROM
  text_post
UNION
 SELECT 
  postid, post_content, post_url, post_user, post_type, post_visibility, post_date 
FROM
  multimedia_post
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do use full outer join on both tables

```
 select post_id,post_content,post_url,post_user,post_type,post_visibility,
 post_date from 
 text_post as tp, multimedia_post as mp 
 on tp.post_id = mp.post_id
```