# Merge two rows of same table with common fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to merge the rows where col1 and col2 are same(here last two rows) with the below conditions

-Priority row - row where 'ManualUpdate' Column is 'Yes'

Ex: Row4(Col3)<>Row5(Col3),then Row5(Col3)

I have tried with **'JOIN'** and using **CASE Statement**.But no luck :(

Suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: U need to use unions, check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879888/how-to-combine-rows-of-2-tables-having-some-columns-same-and-some-different

Comment: What if two YES rows for a col1/col2 combination?

Comment: Not Sure,but what about this??
 select distinct * from table_name order by case when Manual_Update='Yes' 
    then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 0):

Return all rows with Manual Update = YES.
Also return rows that doesn't have same c1/c2 with Manual Update = YES.

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
from tablename t1
where "Manual update" = 'YES'
   or NOT EXISTS (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
                    and t2."Manual update" = 'YES')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.  You want to have priority column by column, with the values sometimes coming from the manual update column and sometimes from the other.

Here is one method that first looks for the manual update value.  If it is not present, it will take any value:

```
select t.col1, t.col2,
       coalesce(max(case when [Manual Update]= 'Yes' then col3 end), max(col3) ) as col3,
       coalesce(max(case when [Manual Update]= 'Yes' then col4 end), max(col4) ) as col4,
       coalesce(max(case when [Manual Update]= 'Yes' then col5 end), max(col5) ) as col5,
       coalesce(max(case when [Manual Update]= 'Yes' then col6 end), max(col6) ) as col6,
       (case when min([Manual Update]) = max([Manual Update]) then min([Manual Update]) end) as [Manual Update]
from table t
group by t.col1, t.col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `COALESCE` operator.

```
select A.Col1, 
A.Col2, 
coalesce(B.Col3, A.Col3),
coalesce(B.Col4, A.Col4)
coalesce(B.Col5, A.Col5)
coalesce(B.Col6, A.Col6)
from Tbl A left join Tbl B 
on A.Col1 = B.Col1 and A.Col2 = B.Col2 
and A.[Manual Update] = 'No' and B.[Manual Update] = 'Yes'
```

Basically, you have to perform `self join` with one side being the row with `Manual Update` column set to `no` and other side to yes. `Coalesce` function works in a way to *prefer* the values from the row which have `Manual Update` set to `yes`